# Trouble in sorting vector strings using std::sort() using custom compare function

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I am trying to sort strings according to a rule. The c++ code works in most cases but in some cases gives an error:

```
  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

I have seen this error before, it happens when we try to initialize a string as null pointer or 0 (which is internally converted as a null pointer). I have checked that error is happening during sorting and only when I use the custom function for comparison. Once again, I don't know why it is happening only in certain cases.

The code is:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

bool greater(string a, string b) {
  int i = 0;
  a = a + a[0];
  b = b + b[0];
  while(i<a.size() && i<b.size()) {
    if(a[i] != b[i]) {
      if(a[i] - '0' > b[i] - '0')
      return true;
      else return false;
    }
    i++;
  }
  
}

string largest_number(vector<string> a) {
  std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), greater);
  std::stringstream ret;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    ret << a[i];
  }
  string result;
  ret >> result;
  return result;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  vector<string> a(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    std::cin >> a[i];
  }
  std::cout << largest_number(a);
  return 0;
}
```

One of the cases where it gives error is:

```
100  
2 8 2 3 6 4 1 1 10 6 3 3 6 1 3 8 4 6 1 10 8 4 10 4 1 3 2 3 2 6 1 5 2 9 8 5 10 8 7 9 6 4 2 6 3 8 8 9 8 2 9 10 3 10 7 5 7 1 7 5 1 4 7 6 1 10 5 4 8 4 2 7 8 1 1 7 4 1 1 9 8 6 5 9 9 3 7 6 3 10 8 10 7 2 5 1 1 9 9 5
```

SOLUTION:
Thanks for help. The error was occurring as the compare function was not returning anything once it goes out of the loop. Here is the updated function that works.

```
bool greater(string a, string b) {
  int i = 0;
  a = a + a[0];
  b = b + b[0];
  while(i<a.size() && i<b.size()) {
      if(a[i] > b[i])
        return true;
    i++;
  }
  return false; 
}
```

Comment: What does your compare function return when comparing "app" with "apple"? ;) I don't know if and how this is producing the error, but it seems to me that one return statement is missing.

Comment: Not a bug, but `a[i] - '0' > b[i] - '0'` is equivalent to `a[i] > b[i]`, and `if (x > y) return true; else return false;` is equivalent to `return x > y;`.

Comment: What is the point of `a = a;` and `b = b;`?

Comment: Just FWIW: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/ . It works because [std::string already implements the basic relational operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/).

Comment: Is there a reason or a specific requirement to read, sort and output `std::string`s instead of `int`s?

Comment: @molbdnilo, I know in fact the topmost if statement is also not required. I was just tweaking with the code.

Comment: @Bob__ Sorry for the confusion, I have edited it. It was required for the problem that I was trying to solve. I was just randomly changing things and removed that part.

Comment: @PrashantSingh Removing the outer `if` would change the meaning dramatically, and be wrong.

Comment: @molbdnilo, yeah I know. Look at the edit, I was meaning it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem I can see with the code (actually I tried in an online compiler and it gave me this warning) is that you don't return anything from `greater` if the two strings are equal:

```
bool greater(string a, string b) {
  int i = 0;
  a = a;
  b = b;
  while(i<a.size() && i<b.size()) {
    if(a[i] != b[i]) {
      if(a[i] - '0' > b[i] - '0')
      return true;
      else return false;
    }
    i++;
  }
  // <---- what about here?
}
```

Try inserting a return statement. (Of course, if two things are equal then neither is greater than the other, so specifically it is a `return false` you want.) Falling off the end of a function without a `return` statement is *undefined behaviour* (except for `int main()` or any function returning `void`), so you could expect to see anything at all when this happens, including the type of crash you got.

[Edit: as gst says, you also get to that point if one string is a prefix of the other e.g. `"1"` and `"10"`. So you'll need a bit more code to test which is which, rather than just a `return false`. But you could see if that one line would fix the crash: it would be logically wrong but at least not undefined behaviour.]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I can't believe the I missed it. The error made me think it should be related to string initialization.